# This webpage is not available error when running Drupal Commerce Kickstart 2 installatgion

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, installation

I am attempting to play with Drupal Commerce and have set up WAMP on a Windows 7 machine. I have updated the curl DLL to be the correct one for WAMP as per instructions from Drupal Commerce pagef. I've then extracted the files into a folder called "ecomtest" and then browse to

```
http://localhost:8080/ecomtest
```

but instead of the Welcome screen for Drupal Commerce I get "This webpage is not available" There is a slight pause before this comes up, but I have tried in two clean directories and this problem persists. Has anyone had this issue and how do I solve it?

Comment: Did u find any solution for that ?